# Placing HTML element next to SVG using viewbox coordinates

Tags: html, css, svg

I've looked around but I keep seeing different answers with mixed results. I want to place a html element next to an inline svg, but position the html element using that svg's viewbox. something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 250 250"/>
  <div class="inner"/> <!-- Want to position it using svgs viewBox -->
</div>
```

Comment: can u create stackblitz sample pls

Comment: What does a viewBox have to do with placing an HTML element next to an SVG element? a viewBox controls how the internal contents of the SVG element are displayed, it does not control where the SVG element is positioned.

Comment: I want to position the HTML element as if it were inside the svg element, using the viewbox coordinates as reference.

Comment: Why not just put the HTML element in the SVG. It's allowed, I think.

Comment: Yeah, one can do that using ForeignObject, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Can you describe in more details where the HLML element should be placed in relation to the view box?

Answer (score 0):

The SVG that has no defined width or height will expand to the container. So, if the width of the SVG is 100%, a "unit" for the div must be `100% / 250` if the viewBox has the width of 250.

In the example I place the div 50 units from the top and centered in the middle. So, from the top, 50 times the "unit": `100% / 250 * 50`. And the center point is `100% / 250 * 125` and then minus `50px` because the div is 100px in width.

Is it something like that?

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  border: thin solid black;
}

div.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% / 250 * 50);
  left: calc(100% / 250 * 125 - 50px);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  border: thin solid green;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 250 250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="250" height="250" fill="orange"/>
    <circle cx="125" cy="50" r="2" fill="red" />
  </svg>
  <div class="inner">Inner</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. So in other words, it is necessary to know the width of the svg or the container in order to calculate it's position relative to the viewbox?

Comment: @Dobby1235 yes, that is the assumption. I guess in most cases you would know either the width of the SVG and/or the width of the container. Maybe you could add an example to your question that is more specific, so that I can code something that is closer to what you need.